# Pydantic model w Fastapi doesnt see properties

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

**schemas.py**

```
import pydantic as _pydantic
import datetime as _dt

class _UserBase(_pydantic.BaseModel):
    email = str


class UserCreate(_UserBase):
    hashed_password = str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

**main.py**

```
import fastapi as _fastapi
import fastapi.security as _security
import sqlalchemy.orm as _orm
import services as _services
import schemas as _schemas

app = _fastapi.FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
def get():
    m = _schemas.UserCreate.schema_json()
    return m
```

When i go to localhost:8000/ it returns:

```
"{\"title\": \"UserCreate\", \"type\": \"object\", \"properties\": {}}"
```

And i cant see the request body inside swagger doc also. It comes empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [official `pydantic` tutorial](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/), you should use type annotations, not assign the types as class variables:

```py
class _UserBase(_pydantic.BaseModel):
    email: str
```